# Redirect to apex page and set error message to be displayed

Tags: oracle, redirect, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a process that runs when a page is submitted. In the process I am catching an exception and if an exception occurs, I want to redirect to a different page and display the error message of the exception.

The redirect in my code works but I want to set an error message to display on page 765 which is a different page to the one with this process on.

```
begin

    -- some code here

exception when others then
    -- how to set the exception error message to show on page 765?
    owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:765:&SESSION.::NO:::');

end;
```

Answer (score 2):

**SQLERRM** returns error message, and **SQLCODE** the code:

```
begin

    -- some code here

exception when others then
    :P765_ERROR_CODE := SQLCODE;
    :P765_ERROR_MSG := SQLERRM;
    owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=&APP_ID.:765:&SESSION.::NO:::');

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also look at the [apex_error API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/apex_error.htm#BGBEEGIB) (I believe it was introduced in 4.0? It's in 4.1 for sure.). This allows you to process errors in your page or application, and alter how they are displayed.
It allows you to for example catch your error, set the error location to the error page (which has a template by the way!) and alter the message and additional info. It could remove the need to do specific redirects just to have your error displayed in a certain way.
If you would need to display additional results and such, you can use the redirect approach of course.

Comment: I didn't know about that until now, it sounds like a good approach.